# Making a div and a button appear in a JavaScript function together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a test that runs a series of trials, and if the user gets a certain amount of answers wrong, then it should show a warning message and a restart button. The function is here below. I have put the JQuery calls inside the JS check function. Strangely, only the restart button is showing, and even more strange is that when I click the restart button, then the warning text appears.

```
function checkWrongAnswers() {
    if (wrongAnswers == 1) {
        clearInterval(theTask);
        $("#warning").toggle();
        $(".btn[name=restartANT]").show();
    }
}
```

The JQuery code for when the restart button is clicked is below. I show the instructions page and hide the restart button, and show the forward button. I don't understand why the error text appears after the restart button is clicked, and not before.

```
    $(".btn[name=restartANT").click(function() {
        $("#antInstructions01").toggle();
        $(".btn[name=restartANT").hide();
        $("#forwardBtn").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: show html, why `#warning` is `toggle()`  ?

Comment: I hide #warning at the start of $document.ready, and toggle it here. Same problem when I use show().

Comment: so `#warning` is `id` of `div` . And it contains button. Or button outside of `div` ...!! You should provide html in your question.

Comment: HTML for the button/div
 <button class="btn antBtn" type="button" name="restartANT">Restart</button>
 <div id="warning">
  <span id="antText3">
   Your test has been terminated because you have got 5 trials wrong. Please read the instructions before you take the test again.
  </span>
 </div>

Comment: change position and try .... in your restart button click function. first hide restart btn and then toggle instruction and forwardbtn

Comment: try this `$("#warning .btn[name=restartANT]").show();`

Comment: Changing positions didn't work and nothing appears now with that show function!

Comment: i can't solve without html add your html in question ..

Comment: The HTML is too long. I can't post it all.